# Using a handle with nested dragula and slice

Tags: javascript, nested, dragula

I am looking to add the use of a handle to the following nested dragula example but it seems impossible.  Any idea how to modify the script for using handles instead of the whole div being draggable:

```
(function() {
  dragula([].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.nested')));
})();
```

The full script is here:
https://codepen.io/trzmaxim/pen/GppXGE

Dragula can be found here:
https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/

Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 1):

i just had a look at the docs and found this:

```
(function() {
  dragula([].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.nested')),{
     moves: function (el, container, handle) {
       return handle.classList.contains('handle');
     }
  });
})();
```

you just have to add an element with class handle into each item, i tried out with your codepen and it works!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgBNje

Comment: Thanks a ton, I forked this to help me solve a problem that went a little bit deeper: https://codepen.io/stufu/pen/LXNdBL